# Passing int[][] as generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

```
public static <T> void func1(T[][] arr) {
    ...
}
```

```
public static <T> void func2(T[] arr) {
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to pass a 2-dimensional array, `int[][] arr`.

I cannot use `func1(arr)` , but I can use `func2(arr)`

Can someone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 25):

`T[]` represents an array of some generic object.  Any array type (including `int[]`) is an object.  Therefore, `int[][]` is a valid `T[]` when `T = int[]`.

However, because `int` is not an object, `int[][]` is not a valid `T[][]`.

Comment: To expand on this, you could change it to Integer[][] arr; and it should work.

Comment: @LadyCailin true, but in most cases when you need multi-dimensional arrays, it is really bad idea to use wrapper types

Answer (score 2):

If you you use `Integer` instead of `int`, you should be able to:

- call `func1` with `Integer[][] arr`
- call `func2` with `Integer[] arr` or `Integer[][] arr`